# Is there a reason to retrieve env variables outside a Python function vs. inside if only used for that function?

Tags: python, function, environment-variables

If environment variables are *only* used by a single function, is there a reason to define them outside the function itself?

**Example:**

```
# Env variables retrieved **inside** function

def retrieve_keyvault_secrets(kv_client):
    try:
        dl_s3_access_key = kv_client.get_secret(os.environ["S3_AK_SECRET_NAME"])
        dl_s3_secret_key = kv_client.get_secret(os.envrion["S3_SK_SECRET_NAME"])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error retrieving key vault secrets: {e}')
    return dl_s3_access_key, dl_s3_secret_key
```

**vs.**

```
# Env variables defined **outside** function and passed in

dl_s3_access_key = os.environ["S3_AK_SECRET_NAME"]
dl_s3_secret_key = os.envrion["S3_SK_SECRET_NAME"]

def retrieve_keyvault_secrets(kv_client, dl_s3_access_key, dl_s3_secret_key):
    try:
        dl_s3_access_key = kv_client.get_secret(dl_s3_access_key)
        dl_s3_secret_key = kv_client.get_secret(dl_s3_secret_key)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error retrieving key vault secrets: {e}')
    return dl_s3_access_key, dl_s3_secret_key
```

Comment: No, there is no reason.  Personal preference.  As a general rule, a variable's lifetime should be as short as possible, and that argues for your first snippet.

Comment: Being new to Python, I appreciate the validation!